# console window starts behind gui

Tags: c#, console-application

I have created a gui for server but whenever I start gui a console window also opens and if I close console window the gui also closes. The console window doesn't do anything it just opens when I start my gui. How can I avoid this? I want only gui to start and not console window.

```
namespace ServerUI
{
public partial class Server : Form
{
    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //default port number
        textBox1.Text = "8001";

        button1.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    //Global Variables
    public static class Globals
    {
        public const string IP = "127.0.0.1";

        public static int port_number = 0;
        public static string selected = "";
        public static string selected_1 = "";
    }

    //IP address of server
    static IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Globals.IP);

    //List of active clients connected to server
    List<Socket> active_clients = new List<Socket>();

    static Socket serverSocket;
    static byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Port Number Empty", "Error");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            bool check = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out Globals.port_number);
            if (!check)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Port Number not in correct format. Enter Port Number again", "Error");
                return;
            }
            client_pkt_parsing.client_list.Clear();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                myRow.Cells[1].Value = null; // assuming you want to clear the first column
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                myRow.Cells[1].Value = null; // assuming you want to clear the first column
            }
            //Starting Server
            StartServer();
        }
    } //end of button1_Click

    public void StartServer()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Globals.port_number);

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            serverSocket.Listen(10);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            infoBox.Text = "Server started. Waiting for a connection...";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }//end of StartServer

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();
        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
            infoBox.Text = infoBox.Text + "\r\n" + string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " > Client : " + clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "connected");
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), clientSocket);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }//end of AcceptCallback

    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int received = 0;
            Socket current = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            received = current.EndReceive(ar);
            byte[] data = new byte[received];

            if (received == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            Array.Copy(buffer, data, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            testBox.Text = testBox.Text + "\r\n" + text;
            //Send(current, "hello");
            buffer = null;
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, current.ReceiveBufferSize);

            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), current);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }//end of RecieveCallback


}
}
```

Comment: Those are called host terminals, are you creating the GUI in an app that normally runs in a terminal? Show some code, maybe? And some details also please.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console or GUI in the settings?

Comment: its a gui not console

Comment: Are you running this from your IDE's start icon (usually debug), or from the .exe file generated?

Comment: sorry I am new to .net where is IDE start icon I am starting gui from .exe file inside debug folder.

Comment: That is why you get a host terminal then, do release build and start that EXE file. IDE is your environment, the software you develop with.

Comment: can you please explain in detail I did release build but console window still starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens when you started with the wrong project template.  It is fixable.  Use Project + Properties, Application tab.  Change the "Output type" setting from Console Application to Windows Application.  No more console.